# How can I add two elements in a list in this manner?

Tags: python, list, syntax, append, extend

So I'm trying to find how can I append two items into my new list `r` under the function `histogram`. I've learnt that using extend, I am able to use commas to add more than one element each time. However, when I tried to do this, I get an error message saying

`TypeError: list.extend() takes exactly one argument (2 given)`

What am I doing wrong here?? Am I misunderstanding the syntax of the `list.extend` function?

Here is my code btw..

```
def reverse(filename):
    s = open(filename, 'r')
    content = s.read()
    return list(content)
print(reverse('data'))

def histogram(filename):
    g: list = reverse(filename)
    r = []
    for x in g:
        r.extend(x, g.count(x))
    return r

print(histogram('data'))
```

Comment: Maybe you meant to do `r.extend([x, g.count(x)])`? At any rate `list.extend` takes only one argument

Comment: You first **read up on the API method you use**, then you supply it an iterabel (list,tuple, ...) of values instead of multiple params. Python is well documented - why ask how it works instead of looking it up - that is called research and the first thing you do before asking. Read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

As the error message mentions, `extend` receives one argument only, a list, and concatenate it to the list that calls the function. If you want to add a single element to a list, use `append`. For example:

```
a = [1, 2]
b = [3, 4]

b.extend(a)
print(b) # [3, 4, 1, 2]

b.append(5)
print(b) # [3, 4, 1, 2, 5]
```

In order to add 2 elements into your list, you can do:

```
r.extend([x, g.count(x)])
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to answer given by @Gabip,

**"I've learnt that using extend, I am able to use commas to add more than one element each time"**, you can consider it as the incomplete information of the `extend` function.

To further clarify between `extend` and `append`. `append` adds the argument as a single value at the end of the `list` and `extend` iterates over its argument and add it at the end of the `list`.

```py
x = [1, 2, 3]

"""list.append"""
x.append(2)
>>> [1, 2, 3, 2]

x.append([2, 3])
>>> [1, 2, 3, [2, 3]]

"""list.extend"""
x.extend(2)
>>> TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

x.extend([2])
>>> [1, 2, 3, 2]

x.extend([ [2] ])
>>> [1, 2, 3, [2]]
```